# Elasticsearch: search words connected by, ends with or contain a specific symbol

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-query

I am new to Elasticsearch and still learning it. I have an index named `article`. The documents in the index has a field called `body` which contains text of an article. The language of the texts is `Hindi`.

I wish to find words connected by a special symbol `hyphen(-)`.

If I search for an article by id, I get the results like below:

```
GET /article/_doc/<some id>

{
  "_index" : "article",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "<some id>",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_seq_no" : 495,
  "_primary_term" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source" : {
    "web_source" : "<some source>",
    "web_url" : "<some url>",
    "body" : """
 ... उत्तर-पूर्व में चीन, नेपाल और भूटान, पूर्व में बांग्लादेश और म्यान्मार स्थित हैं। हिन्द महासागर में इसके दक्षिण पश्चिम में मालदीव, दक्षिण में श्रीलंका और दक्षिण-पूर्व में इंडोनेशिया से भारत की सामुद्रिक सीमा लगती है। इसके उत्तर की भौतिक सीमा हिमालय पर्वत से और दक्षिण में हिन्द महासागर से लगी हुई है। पूर्व में बंगाल की खाड़ी है तथा पश्चिम में अरब सागर हैं। ...
  """,
      "updated" : "<some date>"
  }
}
```

Clearly, the body field contains words such as `दक्षिण-पूर्व` and `उत्तर-पूर्व`. I wish to find all such words.

When I run the following query, it gives me a number of results, one of them being the document above.

```
GET /article/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "body" : "उत्तर-पूर्व"
        }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        "fields" : {
            "body" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: I have tried the below query without any gains i.e. it returns 0 hits.**

```
POST /article/_doc/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "wildcard": {
                        "body": "*-*"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your article-index configured with the hindi language analyzer?

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill I guess it is not. I have done the default indexing.

Comment: @inquilabee, did you get a chance to go through my answer?

Comment: Hey! Thanks. Do you have an answer to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/408532/362506

Comment: @inquilabee, sorry I don't work hv exp. on automatic sync solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you are using the default mapping, which would use the default standard analyzer, which would remove the `-` while indexing, hence you are not getting when searching for `*_*`.

[match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) is analyzed which uses the same analyzer which was used at the index time, hence it would also remove the `-` for search terms, that is why it gave results. From the same doc of the match query:

> Returns documents that match a provided text, number, date or boolean
>   value. The provided text is analyzed before matching.

**Solution** :- use [the custom analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) if you want to search for `_` as well, which uses the keyword tokenizer with lower case, as I verified and [Hindi analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#hindi-analyzer) also removes the `-`.

**Tokens generated with Hindi analyzer**

```
POST /article/_analyze --> noyte `-` removed

{
    "analyzer" : "hindi",
    "text" : "उत्तर-पूर्व"
}

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "उततर",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 5,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "पुरव",
            "start_offset": 6,
            "end_offset": 11,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

**Custom analyzer def (lowercasekeyword)**

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "lowercasekeyword": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Tokens generated with above custom analyzer**

```
POST articles/_analyze
{
    "analyzer" : "lowercasekeyword",
    "text" : "उत्तर-पूर्व"
}

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "उत्तर-पूर्व",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 11,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

**Important note:** you should create another field and on which include this `lowercasekeyword` analyzer and use it for your wildcard searches. As mentioned earlier `match` queries are analyzed and wouldn't work on this field.

Answer (score 0):

When using Elasticsearch, it is important to understand how your documents are tokenized. The default Elasticsearch indexes use the [Standard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) analyzer, which removes most punctuation from the document. This is probably the reason you can't search for hyphens. You can use the [Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) to understand how your documents are broken into tokens.